# In node-red, how to retrieve the current node's properties programmatically?

Tags: node-red

For example, if creating a custom logging function stored in the global or flow context, how would this function retrieve the name of the node calling it, for that node to use as console output?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this, as none of the required functions are in scope in the settings.js or the function node (where you update something in the global context).

You may do better discussing what your aims are here in more detail on the Node-RED Google Group or Slack channel both of which are linked to from the Node-RED [home page](http://nodered.org/).

Comment: My aim is to avoid bad practice by hard-coding the names of nodes into custom logging code. If and when any nodes have their names changed, those will have to be re-entered in the logging code.  Obviously it'd be better to include the name information as a reference to its source rather than doubling up. It'd further be handy to be able to update node names programmatically, similar to how the status light can be updated.